# The best way to convert Success into Failure depending on the value of Success

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I use Play! Framework with ReactiveMongo plugin (versions 2.3 and 0.11 accordingly). And I have the next code which removes items from MongoDB collection and returns a number of affected items:

```
/**
  * Removes all subscribers by subscription id
  * 
  * @param subscriptionId id of the subscription
  * @return count of removed subscribers
  */  
def deleteAll(subscriptionId: String): Future[Int] = {
      logger.debug(s"Removing all subscribers with subscription id '$subscriptionId'...")
      val query = BSONDocument("subscriptionId" -> BSONObjectID(subscriptionId))
      subscribersCollection.remove(query) map { writeResult: WriteResult =>
        writeResult.n match {
          case subscribersRemoved if subscribersRemoved > 0 =>
            logger.debug(s"Successfully removed $subscribersRemoved subscribers with subscribtion id '$subscriptionId'")
          case _ => logger.debug(s"No subscribers with subscribtion id '$subscriptionId' were removed")
        }
        writeResult.n
      }
  }
```

Due to ReactiveMongo documentation, `WriteResult` class returned by collection's `remove()` method has fields such as `hasError` and `writeErrors` to indicate errors that occurred during the execution of the database query.

So what is the best and cleanest way to enhance my method in order to return a Failure from it depending on `WriteResult`'s `hasError` field?

Here is rough example:

```
subscribersCollection.remove(query).??? match {
  case Success(writeResult) if writeResult.hasErrors => Failure(new DatabaseException(writeResult.errMsg, writeResult.code)
  case any => any
}
```

I.e. my method should return a `Failure` even if a database query returns a `Success` with error fields

Thanks in advance! I really would appreciate any help in order to make my code better

P.S. I have considered wrapping all of my code in `Try` and just throwing an exception on `hasError` flag set to `true`, but I believe that it can be done in a better way, maybe with `Future`'s `transform()` method

P.P.S. For some reason code samples and demos from ReactiveMongo [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html) do not handle `WriteError`'s error fields and flags. In fact, the documentation says

> If the write result actually indicates an error, the Future will be in
>   a failed state

However, I've already seen such handling in production code in a couple of applications, so it is slightly confusing. Does it mean that this kind of handling is excessive?

Comment: ReactiveMongo 0.11 is quite obsolete now. The handling of `WriteResult` is documented for newer version : http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html

Comment: Thank you. The migration is in plans, but for now does it mean that "no need to check for WriteResult.ok" is appliable for WriteResult of 0.11 too?

Comment: There cannot be a successful `Future[WriteResult]` if there is a fatal MongoDB error/failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `flatMap` and `Future.failed`**

do `flatMap` on the `Future` and then based on the value return `Future.failed(new Exception("unexpected value"))`

Lets say we have a function which returns a future of some int

```
def httpStatus: Future[Int] = Future { 404 }

httpStatus.flatMap { 
 case 404 => //return failed future
  Future.failed(new Exception("Bad status"))
 case value => value
}
```

Now your code becomes

```
def deleteAll(subscriptionId: String): Future[Int] = {
      logger.debug(s"Removing all subscribers with subscription id '$subscriptionId'...")
      val query = BSONDocument("subscriptionId" -> BSONObjectID(subscriptionId))
      subscribersCollection.remove(query) flatMap { writeResult: WriteResult =>
        writeResult.n match {
          case subscribersRemoved if subscribersRemoved > 0 =>
            logger.debug(s"Successfully removed $subscribersRemoved subscribers with subscribtion id '$subscriptionId'")
            Future.successful(writeResult.n)
          case status => 
             logger.debug(s"No subscribers with subscribtion id '$subscriptionId' were removed")
             Future.failed(new Exception(s"bad status exception. status: $status"))
        }

      }
  }
```